# Looking for a smart command-line tool in Linux which can generate xsd out of xml

Tags: linux, command-line, xsd, generator, xsd.exe

I can also settle for a web-based interface, but a good command-line tool is preferable. Now, I have tried to use xsd.exe that comes with mono-devel, but that skipped a whole bunch of stuff that was mentioned in the xml file.

I understand that I will need to hand-tweak the output, but I do want something decent to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Try the tool that comes with the spring framework:

http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/